# python data structures for storing classes

Tags: python, database

I am trying to design a system in python where my customers can create an order and it will be stored in an array or similar type of structure that will be able to constantly expand to store more orders as they are placed. What is the best way to do this?

Comment: A list? A dict? Quite honestly, this is way too broad for stack overflow.

Answer (score 0):

I can think of two ways to do this.

1. Serialization. [Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/355730/the-best-way-to-store-class-instances-to-a-file-database)
2. Create two tables, One called Order and other called order_contents. You can join order and Order_contents by order id. Store Order specific data in order table and content specific data in conetnt. All contents can be retrieved with a single SQL query this way OR in python, easily with ORM.

Answer (score 0):

How big would you expect and order to get and how many orders could there be? Also what is stored in an order?

If you use numpy arrays you have the problem that increasing the size of an array is a very expensive process, so doing it many times on large arrays would be problematic. Numpy arrays also are for data that is all the same type, so you would not use this for things that are combinations of strings (name, item), integers (item reference), and floats (cost).

A simple list is likely the easiest and most inclusive choice. You can put whatever you like in a list and increase the size easily since a list is actually just pointers.

A dictionary could be useful if you are expecting to have to search the list often, or have a clear key-item relationship.

It really comes down to your use case. A list is often the choice, but a dictionary could be nice, and numpy arrays are nice if you are doing math with the stored data.

Comment: I did not realize you were explicitly using classes. You will likely want lists then since they are the simplest for using classes and other structures.